# Defect in linked list in Python

Tags: python

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,data):
           self.data=data
           self.next=None   
head=Node(5)
trys=head
trys=trys.next
trys=Node(7)
print(head.next.data)
```

Here print would give error. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because `trys=Node(7)` is **not** the same thing is actually assigning to `head.next`.

Comment: For the same reason that `trys=trys.next` does not change the value of `head`, so also `trys=Node(7)` does not change the value of `trys.next`.

Comment: can you explain how could i  write then?

Comment: `head.next = Node(7)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `trys=head` creates a new variable which is pointed to `head`.

The line `trys=trys.next` re-assigns the variable `trys` to `head.next`.

The line `trys=Node(7)` re-assigns `trys` to `Node(7)`.  But the variable `trys` has no "memory" that it is "really" head.next - that is irrelevant.  All we are doing here is re-assigning a variable named `trys`.

Thus, `head.next` remains unassigned, and therefore `head.next.data` will throw an error, because you are attempting to access a property of an undefined value.